# C# XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: c#

How do I convert XMLGregorianCalendar to C# DateTime? We have C# client application that receives data from Java server and one of type of the field is defined as XMLGregorianCalendar in Java and C# will be receving this as  a string (XMLGregorianCalendar.toXMLFormat()). How can I convert this into a DateTime instance?

Thanks

Comment: Yo do know that the Greg calendar is simply _the_ calendar, right?

Comment: XMLGregorianCalendar in the java 1.5 documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add over your `XMLGregorianCalendar` field annotation:

@XmlSchemaType(name="dateTime")

It will map this field in wsdl to `xs:dateTime` which generate in your C# webservice proxy class `DateTime` property.